# Groovy String interpolation not being passed correctly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a command in Jenkins using `sh`. Here is what I do:

```
ecsOracleClusterName = "foo"
ecsServiceName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'aws ecs list-services --cluster "${ecsOracleClusterName}" --region us-east-1').trim()
```

What I have noticed is that `ecsOracleClusterName` comes up blank. Not sure why this is happening but in Jenkins, I get this error message:

```
+ aws ecs list-services --cluster  --region us-east-1

An error occurred (ClusterNotFoundException) when calling the ListServices operation: Cluster not found.
```

As you see, the cluster name variable is not passing the value. This leads me to believe that there is a problem with String interpolation (or atleast how I am implementing it). Can someone please tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using double quotes like so ..

```
ecsOracleClusterName = "foo"
ecsServiceName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ecs list-services --cluster $ecsOracleClusterName --region us-east-1").trim()
println "Service name: ${ecsServiceName}"
```

Comment: If I do that, would I need to add opening and closing brackets to the variable?

Comment: Nope, try it exactly as written